# How can I segment a DataFrame pandas into N DataFrames based its structure?

Tags: python, pandas, database, dataframe, data-structures

I'm creating a software to plot graphs using Excel data imported by the user. I'm using PyQt5 to create interface and matplotlib to create plots. To import data from Excel I'm using pandas read_excel, that saves the Excel data as a DataFrame.
I've created a class to handle this data and do some analysis. Actually, this class collects a bunch of information about the data structure. What I want to do is to use these information to split the raw DataFrame into different single DataFrames (datasets). The following dictionaries are some of returns from the class after doing some code over the raw DataFrame:
`resumeCol = {'string': [18], 'number': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37], 'empty': [0, 17, 19]}`
`resumeRow = {'string': [], 'number': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41], 'empty': []}`

Each of the items inside the lists are columns/rows indexes from the Excel table that holds the characteristic from the dictionary keys. So, for example, in this data imported, the column index 18 is string data, and indexes 0, 17, 19 are empty columns. Here you have a quick view from how is the data as a Excel file and as a DataFrame:[Excel data vs DataFrame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ezTEq.png)

By now, I'm able to know the ranges to split the data in N datasets, using this function:

```
def range_data(self, resumeCol):
    number = resumeCol['number']
    limit = []
    ranges = {}
    cont = 1
    for i, row in enumerate(number):
        if i == 0:
            limit.append(row)
        elif i == len(number) - 1:
            limit.append(row)
            ranges[str(cont)] = limit
        else:
            if row != number[i + 1] - 1:
                limit.append(row)
                if len(limit) == 2:
                    ranges[str(cont)] = limit
                    limit = []
                    cont += 1
                    limit.append(number[i + 1])
```

Now I want to use the 'string' and 'empty' information to get the identification of each dataset.
Having the data from the image [Excel data vs DataFrame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ezTEq.png) as an example. I would like to have
`{'Sample A': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16], 'Sample B': [20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37]}`

I'll be really grateful to have even a inside from you. Appreciate!
(obs: English is not my mother tong, so excuse my typo)

Comment: Welcome to SO! Your English is fine. What's not so fine is that your question needs some polishing. Instead of narrating your whole project, it would be very helpful to write a minimal dataframe that encapsulates what you are working with, and to state what you want to do with it. The member function you provide is part of a larger class that we can't see, therefore we can't know how to use it to help you either. Finally, posting images is almost never helpful, especially if they are just pieces of a bigger snapshot.

Comment: Thanks for the tips mate. I'll be more careful on my next questions. Appreciate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `groupby`:

```
resumeCol = {'string': [18], 'number': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37], 'empty': [0, 17, 19]}

s = (pd.Series({v: k for k,l in resumeCol.items()
               for v in l})
       .sort_index()
       .eq('number')
     )

out = s.index[s].groupby(s.ne(s.shift())[s].cumsum())
```

Output:

```
{1: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16],
 2: [20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37]}
```

Comment: That works beautifully mate. You made my day, thanks a lot! Now I'll study it and understand how it works.

Comment: If you have any more tips to help me on how to get the labels from the empty columns (if it exists) and relate this labels to the correspondent dataset intervals, it'll be astonishing!

Comment: For that I would need a reproducible input ;)